# jquery mobile, list, hide arrow icon

Tags: jquery, list

I am trying to remove the arrow icon from one list item with a jquery event.

One list item:

```
<li class='message_list'><a id='message_list_item' href='#'>
<h3>Sender</h3>
<p><strong>Subject</strong></p>
<p>Body Text</p>
<p class='ui-li-aside'><strong>Time</strong>am</p>
</a></li>
```

script:

```
$(".message_list").swipeleft(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); //prevent from firing twice
    $(this).attr('data-icon', 'false');
    $("#test_display").html("Worked");      

    return false;
});
```

The test html updates, so the script activates. But why doesn't that attribute change work?

Putting `<li data-icon='false' class='message_list'>` does remove it though!

Answer (score 0):

`data-*` attributes are supported through [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/). Try using -

```
 $(this).data('icon', 'false');
```

and then later you can check using -

```
$(this).data('icon');    // will return false if set to false.
```

Comment: using those the data does change from arrow-r to false (or whatever other icon i set it to) but the icon still displays.

Comment: @Fred: Probably you need to explicitly make the icon visibility to false, or there is some other mechanism to hide it.